# Empty If Optimization

Tags: optimization, language-agnostic

Consider the following:

```c
int status = 0;

while(status < 3)
{
    switch(status)
    {
        case 0:
            // Do something
            break;

        case 1:
            if(cond1 && cond2 || cond3 && cond4)
                ; // status = 1
            else if(cond5)
                status = 2;
            else
                status = 0;
            // there could be more else-if statements
            break;

        case 2:
            // Do something else
            break;
    }
    status++;
}
```

Given that the first if-statement is only there for the sake of readability and that, as showed, its body is empty (because redundant), I was wondering how could a compiler (either a ahead-of-time or just-in-time compiler) possibly optimize this (if any optimization is possible).

Comment: This code does not make much sense and under certain conditions will create an infinite loop.

Comment: The first `if` is functional.  It limits the scope of `else`.

Comment: @PM77-1 Of course it doesn't, but that wasn't the point. I've actually thought that it could be negated in the last else statement making it an else-if statement, but I'm not sure about it. Tried to look at the assembly output without any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a general purpose compiler, the answer is no.

Two optimizations that are closely related however, are the [Data flow optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler#Data-flow_optimizations), which aims to eliminate double calculations and impossible paths in code. Another is [Currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), which aims to optimize a general function with regards to the specific parameter.